# segment fault when calling getlazybitcodemodule

Tags: c++, llvm

I got an segment fault when trying to call function  getLazyBitcodeModule.
The code that causes the fault is shown below:

```
 // Load the bytecode...
  std::string ErrorMsg;
  Module *mainModule = 0;
  OwningPtr<MemoryBuffer> BufferPtr;     
  error_code ec = MemoryBuffer::getFileOrSTDIN(InputFile, BufferPtr);
  if (ec) {
      printf("error loading program '%s': %s\n", InputFile, ec.message().c_str());
      exit(1);
  }

  mainModule = getLazyBitcodeModule(BufferPtr.get(), getGlobalContext(), &ErrorMsg);
```

The gdb debug information is also shown below:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0000000000000241 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000000040630e in ~OwningPtr (this=0x7fffffffdd20, __in_chrg=    <optimized out>) at /usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/OwningPtr.h:45
#2  readBitFile (InputFile=InputFile@entry=0xafec23 "test.bc") at    main.cpp:36
#3  0x0000000000405fce in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffde78) at main.cpp:71
```

Any suggestion to get around the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you look inside the implementation of getLazyBitcodeModule() you'll see the line:

```
R->setBufferOwned(true);
```

The BitcodeReader now owns your buffer and will delete the buffer for you when it gets destroyed.  Your OwningPtr is also freeing that same memory so the double free is causing the segfault.